# Unordered array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a class that represents an unordered array in Ruby? I cannot use array because:

```
[1,2] != [2,1]
```

And I cannot use set because I can only have unique elements. I want a kind of both combinations. A list that doesn't care about ordering and can have more than 1 of the same element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called multiset. Here is [Ruby implementation](http://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/index-en.php).

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have extend the Array class and write your own `==` method. Here is my very experimental attempt:

```
class UnorderedArray < Array
  def ==(other)
    self_copy = self.sort
    other = other.sort
    self_copy == other
  end
end

a = UnorderedArray.new
a << 1 << 2
# [1, 2]

b = UnorderedArray.new
b << 2 << 1
# [2, 1]

a == b
# returns true
```

Comment: I think this is a better and easier idea rather than having a new gem

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
Hash[a.zip(a.map{|x| a.count(x)})] == Hash[e.zip(e.map{|x| e.count(x)})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly cleaner mixin that will work on unsortable arrays and caches the hash value as it is O(n).

```
class UnorderedArray < Array
  def hash
    unless @o && @o == super.hash
      p = Hash.new(0)
      each{ |v| p[v] += 1 }
      @p = p.hash
      @o = super.hash
    end
    @p.hash
  end
  def <=>(b)
    raise "You can't order me"
  end
  def ==(b)
    hash == b.hash
  end
end
```

however `#eql?` will return false unless unless the arrays are in the same order.